# How to hide header title dialog jquery?

Tags: jquery

How to hide header title dialog jquery?
I need for simple view dialog. =)
Example Like this image :

[image]

Any body know?

Comment: Is this a standard jQueryUI dialog / a plugin / or jQuery Mobile?

Comment: this is a jqueryUI Dialog. =)

Comment: Cool, this and code samples really help other users answer your question effectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in CSS use this:

`.ui-widget-header { display: none; }`

or this:

`.ui-dialog-titlebar { display: none; }`

which one goes better, you choose.

Comment: Thanks this is useful for me. =)

Comment: I don't know which browser you are using, but in IE or Chrome you can use F12 to use developer tools. in FireFox get the FireBug plugin and it has the same features as mentioned for IE and Chrome.